# Fast and useful way of storing matrix values in C#

Tags: c#, performance, math, matrix, usability

I need to create a 4x4 matrix class for a 3D engine in C#.
I have seen some other engines storing the matrix values in single float member variables / fields like this:

```
float m11, m12, m13, m14
float m21, m22, m23, m24
float m31, m32, m33, m34
float m41, m42, m43, m44
```

However, I thought storing them in a two dimensional array would be more useful for transformations / calculations with the matrices:

```
float[4][4];
```

I also thought of a one dimensional array - but it looks less self explanatory and wouldn't give me an advantage over the first option:

```
float[16];
```

In C++, I always used the "union" keyword to have all of the above storing possibilites at once. However, C# does not seem to have this keyword, so I have to decide which one I want to use.

What is the fastest way of storing the 4x4 matrix when applying transformations etc.?
Which option would you choose when thinking about usability?

Comment: C# has [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), so you can use `float[4,4]`. My wild guess is that it'd perform as well as the single-dimensional one. Both might perform worse than the sixteen variables because an array is allocated on the heap.

Comment: @millimoose Whether it performs better or worse depends on it's usage.  If it's passed around a lot having a single allocation on the heap could be much better than passing sixteen variables continuously.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I should have said "*accessing* both might be slower" instead.

Comment: Thinking about this, I will probably just perform operations with the matrix itself, methods implemented in the matrix class will be used manipulate the stored floats for example. I think they will get passed around less than being manipulated, so I would keep the 16 float variables this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a two dimensional array:

```
float[,] matrix = new float[4,4];
```

This is different than a jagged array:

```
float[][] matrix = new float[][4];
```

A two dimensional array is, underneath, stored as one big one dimensional array.  The class simply abstracts that away from you and provides accessors that provide two (or more) dimensions.  Because it is stored as a one dimensional array in the back end you will maintain cache/memory locallity.

Comment: Actually, 2D arrays in .Net are rather slow.

Comment: Generally speaking I have found jagged arrays to be faster to access, since each sub array can be accessed using its `Length` property, enabling the compiler to disable bounds checking. However for small arrays I'm not sure that you'd see that much of a difference.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It would depend on the size of the data, whether the sub-arrays are all created together or not, the usage of the data, etc.  You could write code that would perform better with either case, if you were trying to.

Comment: This is the best solution yet, since I forgot the correct / better declaration of two dimensional arrays... however I'd prefer the 16 float variables now due to the discussion in the questions comments.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you have a look on this `CodeProject.com` article, [Efficient Matrix Programming in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3354/Efficient-Matrix-Programming-in-C).

You can also have a look at [Declaring an Array (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287586%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for wide variety of option for defining your own `Matrix` Data Structure.

Comment: The CP article is a bit of overload for my matrix class, since I will only use 4x4 matrices and do only some manipulations with them, e.g. they don't need to be super flexible. But it's a good read though!

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way is using pointers along with the `unsafe` key word. But, this, as the keyword indicates, is unsafe.

for more information about pointers in C# look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx).

Comment: Not necessarily. using `unsafe` would ordinarily disable bounds checking on arrays, however the C# compiler is smart enough to do this for you if you iterate over the array using the built in `Length` property. As ever, the OP is advised to benchmark code rather than just assuming that one way or another 'might' be faster.

Comment: I remember how I boosted image drawing by using unsafe once, but for this matrix problem, I want to avoid unsafe code.

Comment: @Pac-Man you asked for the fastest... any way, I agree you should avoid `unsafe` code.

Comment: @elyashiv: Yeah, this is truly the fastest way, I was not really clear if my last two sentences, I also thought about "usability" with which I meant code readability.